# Where are the maps in the Dungeon Master's Guide from?

Tags: dnd-5e, content-identification, maps

There are several maps in the *Dungeon Master's Guide:*

- a [hex map of Daggerford](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p581848124) and surroundings on page 14
- a map of the [elemental planes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#OuterPlanes) on page 57
- a [sample dungeon map](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/adventure-environments#DungeonFeatures) on page 103
- a [beautiful town map](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/adventure-environments#MappingaSettlement) on page 115
- a [**tactical map** in the image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#Exploration) on page 243
- another [**map in a drawing**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#NoncombatChallenges) on page 261

Including several [maps from Appendix C](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/appendix-c-maps):

- a **windmill** and a house map on page 310
- a **dungeon map** on page 311
- another **dungeon** map on page 312
- a **multi-island coastal town** map on page 313
- a **costal map with a bridge** on page 313
- a **cave system map** on page 314
- a **ship map** on page 314
- a **chasm/dungeon** map on page 315

What are the origins of these maps? Do they have a prior history or associated adventures?

Comment: I would recommend including the ones you already figured out in a community wiki answer rather than in the question body. It would make more sense to have one answer that users can edit if they find an answer than several answers with only a single map.

Comment: I've also removed the generic dnd tag since this is about the sources for the contents of a 5th edition book, and I've removed the history of gaming tag because, well, I just don't see how this question fits into history of gaming, maybe you can elaborate on that a bit.

Comment: I’ve rolled back to a revision that did not include images of all the maps from a paid resource.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- The **[page-14 hex map of Daggerford](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p581848124/e27b48d70)** was created specifically for the DMG, by Mike Schley.
- The **[page-57 elemental planes](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p923843744/e3a80d541)** map was created specifically for the DMG, by Mike Schley.
- The **page-103 sample dungeon map**...
- The **[page-115 beautiful town map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p923843744/eac8c938e)** was created specifically for the DMG, by Mike Schley.
- The **[page-243 tactical map](https://www.instagram.com/p/CFICzkxDwlz/)** was created by Carmen Sinek. According to the comments, the artist used herself as a reference for the redhead, and her husband for the elf. She wrote "I waited like 30 years to be in a D&D book, I put myself in there the first chance I got." which suggests the image was created specifically for the DMG. The tactical map itself is not mentioned.
- The **page-261 map in a drawing**...

And from the Appendix

- The **[page-310 windmill map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p141556452/e1b11d798)**, by Mike Schley, was originally commissioned for the article *Prey for Smiley Bob* in issue #205 of Dungeon magazine, by Chris Perkins.
- The **page-310 house map**...
- The **[page-311 dungeon map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p996068422/e3b40bb65)**, by Mike Schley, is a reworked version of the **unnamed sample dungeon** map from the original 1e DMG (which has a [fascinating connection](http://unfrozencavemandicechucker.blogspot.com/2012/02/dmg-sample-dungeon-part-4-cult-of-fiery.html) to the famous dungeon under the moathouse map from *Village of Hommlet*).
- The **[page-312 dungeon map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p581848124/e3ea9b7a9)**, by Mike Schley, was originally included in the D&D Game Day adventure [Vault of the Dracolich](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/120762/Vault-of-the-Dracolich-DD-Next)
- The **[page-313 multi-island coastal town map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p581848124/e7baafc9)**, by Mike Schley, was originally published in issue #189 of Dungeon Magazine to illustrate the the D&D backdrop article titled *Diyun: The Hanging City* by Will Hindmarch.
- The **[page-313 coastal map with a bridge](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p581848124/e14959387)**, by Mike Schley, depicts the town of Mistwatch, originally published in issue #186 of Dungeon Magazine in accompaniment with the article *Mistwatch* by by Robert J. Schwalb.
- The **[page-314 cave system map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p899177298/eac33fc9)**, by Mike Schley, was originally created for the D&D supplement *Into the Unknown: The Dungeon Survival Handbook*. It was also included in the adventure *Storm King's Thunder* under the title "Dripping Caves".
- The **[page-314 ship map](https://prints.mikeschley.com/p581848124/e3117ef12)**, by Mike Schley and Logan Bonner, is from the Attack of the Tyrentclaw poster map (Side B) included in the D&D Lair Assault adventure *Talon of Umberlee*.
- The **[page-315 chasm/dungeon map](https://media.wizards.com/legacy/dnd/images/dng_vault-of-catharandamus.jpg)** is the Vault of Catharandamus, from the [Tome of Magic (3.5 edition)](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/50000/Tome-of-Magic-Pact-Shadow-and-Truename-Magic-35). [Chris Perkins](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/schley-stack) credits it to Mike Schley (although it does not appear on his website.) There is more to this one, however: the map and entire vault is [based on a map originally appearing in](https://osrgrimoire.blogspot.com/2022/04/b3-derivative-works.html) the 1981 D&D module B3 "[Palace of the Silver Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_of_the_Silver_Princess)". The module is infamous for being recalled right after its initial printing due to an illustration depicting a tied up female. You can find the original map, the "Entrance Level" inside the back cover.

Comment: Big thank you, [Willem Renzema](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15991/willem-renzema) for finding several of the missing maps and making everything much nicer!