# Are there lists tying artists to specific pieces in the DMG?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, art

One of my players asked about acquiring an eversmoking bottle.

I haven't gone page by page through the magic items section of the DMG, so today was the first time I actually looked at the [illustration of that](https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/thumbnails/7/210/1000/1000/636284732172956658.jpeg).

My immediate thought was, Gosh, that looks like it was inspired by M.C. Escher's black and white lizard tessellations, like [Smaller and Smaller](https://uploads1.wikiart.org/images/m-c-escher/not_detected_204750.jpg!Large.jpg) or the Development series (I, [II](https://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/m-c-escher/development-ii.jpg!Large.jpg), and III).

The DMG artist credits list a number of artists, but do not tie them to specific illustrations.  Does a list exist somewhere of who did which illustration, or specifically who did the eversmoking bottle, so that I can see whether their other work shows the influence of Escher?

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to track the artist down on twitter? If you tag a few of the artists maybe someone will know.

Comment: Similar question, but about just the maps in the DMG: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197332/15991  I personally found many of them by going through the list of artists in the front, googling them, and seeing if any of their public portfolios included any of the maps in the DMG. Got lucky finding a few, at least.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you believe one deserves it :)

Comment: @Sleepwave Of course. Typically I like to give about a week or so before marking; in the absence of another answer I would certainly be marking yours correct.

Comment: @Kirt you rock, really hoping someone else comes along with a something special because there's a lot of art in the DMG that I absolutely love and I'd be so excited to find out who to follow for my favorite pieces :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is not, at least not publicly.

This is a problem that spans multiple editions, you can see [this forum thread asking a similar question for the DMG for AD&D](https://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=33848), contributors to that thread were never able to complete their list of artist credits either. This is a pattern that Wizards of the Coast has kept consistent with as evidenced by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/dndbeyond/status/1103093721049059328) where D&D Beyond replied to someone requesting individual artist credits on art. D&D Beyond was was partnering with Wizards of the Coast at the time so if anyone would have access to such information, it would be them.

> We credit artists following Wizards of the Coast's lead. You can see the credits within each book source ToC. Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica, for instance, included artist credit with the interior art and that is reflected in the DDB version. Thanks!

While we could speculate why, I don't know of any public statement they've made about this topic. I wish I could give you a more fulfilling answer!